# In neovim, how do I get a file to open at the same line number I closed it at last time?

Tags: neovim

```
au BufReadPost * if line("'\"") > 1 && line("'\"") <= line("$") | exe "normal! g'\"" | endif
```

This code is valid in vim. It is the syntax of vimscript. It can also work in neovim's configuration file init.vim. how can I achieve the same effect in init.lua?

Comment: Does the implicit jump mark (`'"`) work interactively in neovim? I.e., is it a matter of the script command not working or support for `'"` being non-existing? -- Also, for vim-specific questions, note that [vi.stackexchange.com](https://vi.stackexchange.com) exists.

Comment: Sadly I'm not good at lua and vimscript, thanks for the suggestion, I'll go to [vi.stackexchange.com](https://vi.stackexchange.com/) to find out.

Comment: I am not good at either, either. Nor do I use neovim. But I see that the code is basically an automatic `'"`, which is why I was asking if -- after opening a file -- entering the apostroph, quotation mark sequence interactively jumps to the last position (i.e., it's an issue with the code line) or not (i.e., it's an issue with the underlying feature not supported by neovim).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tested on 0.7.2, if not available, the version may be too low.

```lua
vim.api.nvim_create_autocmd("BufReadPost", {
    pattern = {"*"},
    callback = function()
        if vim.fn.line("'\"") > 1 and vim.fn.line("'\"") <= vim.fn.line("$") then
            vim.api.nvim_exec("normal! g'\"",false)
        end
    end
})
```